# selector is not working

Tags: android

I uses its selection for the list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/arrow"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDescr"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:maxHeight="20dp"
        android:minHeight="20dp" >
    </ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and selector arrow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item><shape>
            <gradient android:angle="90.0" android:endColor="#6495ED" android:startColor="#0000FF" android:type="linear" />

            <corners android:radius="5.0dp" />
        </shape></item>
    <item android:state_focused="true"><shape>
            <gradient android:angle="90.0" android:endColor="#BA55D3" android:startColor="#800080" android:type="linear" />

            <corners android:radius="5.0dp" />
        </shape></item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true"><shape>
            <gradient android:angle="90.0" android:endColor="#BA55D3" android:startColor="#800080" android:type="linear" />

            <corners android:radius="5.0dp" />
        </shape></item>

</selector>
```

the result is

[image]

- does not work but if I remove (sources below) it will work

```
<item><shape>
                <gradient android:angle="90.0" android:endColor="#6495ED" android:startColor="#0000FF" android:type="linear" />

                <corners android:radius="5.0dp" />
            </shape></item>
```

[image]

but it does not give me the desired result, because after you click on the "list-button" style has to change - but this does not happen

**I want to make:**

1)Style before pressing as in the picture 1

2)After I press the button, the button style has to change as the 2 picture

3)remain that way until I click on another button
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a selector is a 'state-list-drawable', ie it 'selects' `<items>` depending upon the state of the view it is applied to.

> A StateListDrawable is a drawable object defined in XML that uses a
>   several different images to represent the same graphic, depending on
>   the state of the object. For example, a Button widget can exist in one
>   of several different states (pressed, focused, or niether) and, using
>   a state list drawable, you can provide a different background image
>   for each state.

Here is the syntax, as in the docs :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:constantSize=["true" | "false"]
    android:dither=["true" | "false"]
    android:variablePadding=["true" | "false"] >
    <item
        android:drawable="@[package:]drawable/drawable_resource"
        android:state_pressed=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_focused=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_hovered=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_selected=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_checkable=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_checked=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_enabled=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_activated=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_window_focused=["true" | "false"] />
</selector>
```

notice the attributes you can set in the the `<item>`.

here is an example of a typical selector..

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
>
    <item
        android:state_focused="true" 
        android:state_pressed="false" 
android:drawable="@drawable/list_element_focused"   />
    <item
        android:state_focused="true" 
        android:state_pressed="true"
android:drawable="@drawable/list_element_focused_pressed"   />  
    <item
        android:state_focused="false" 
        android:state_pressed="true"
android:drawable="@drawable/list_element_pressed"   />  
    <item
android:drawable="@drawable/list_element_unfocused" />  
</selector>
```

Comment: Yes, I am feeling it is workable, you can tell - on item 3) "remain that way until I click on another button"

Answer (score 1):

Please apply your selector in your listview instead of LinearLayout.

Comment: My listview is ListFragment he can add a selector?