# Is 5dp same as 5.0dp?

Tags: android-layout, android

Reading android code I find out is not uncommon to fill the xml with the second variant, like [here](https://github.com/yfnick/PlanBetter/blob/master/res/layout/tomorrow_task_widget_in.xml). 
To be honest, this alone would be enough for my head to torment me with the question, but then I see code in which the two notations are even mixed, like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12298940/selector-is-not-working) StackOverflow question.

Google wasn't of help, and I couldn't find this question on SO.

Anyone knows what's the difference, if any?

---

**EDIT**

Based on the firsts question I got here, there seems to be no improvement in performance or other things like that when using the second variant, so writing them as float when they can be integers just tells people they can insert decimal values in there. Anything else?

If that's the only reason, I think using the second option it's just like polluting the xml for little to no reason, are there other opinions?

Answer (score 2):

Check out this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension.  It shows the possible values for dimensions.  They are all floats.  So, you can write them either way.

Comment: thank you, I appreciate the documentation link, as said i couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

The 5.0 version is because certain properties accept a float/double value. All in all, 5.0 is the same as 5 when DP are involved.

Comment: could you fill the question with an example when the one is required over the other?

Comment: I don't have a full reference about it to be honest. Usually angles and shapes are floats because you can specify 5.5 (For example) but when talking about sizes that represent pixels and will be used by the measure/layout engine, you need ints.

Answer (score 0):

one is an int the other is a float. They are types of primitives

Answer (score 0):

It is the same. They both have the same values. 5 and 5.0 are of different types. 5 is of type int and 5.0 is of type float/double.